# ¿Cómo puedo crear un reserva de plaza de parking?

Tags: java

Hola buenas ¿Alguien podría ayudarme por favor?

Estoy haciendo la gestión de un parking que almacene la matrícula y la fecha y hora que ha entrado al parking y todo eso lo estoy haciendo con un Arraylist. La cuestión es que no se como guardar en la Arraylist.

He hecho una clase para el método:

```
public class Car {

static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Vehicles> parkingSlots = new ArrayList<Vehicles>();
    ArrayList<Vehicles> dateTimes = new ArrayList<>();

}

public void createReservation(ArrayList<Vehicles> parkingSlots, ArrayList<Vehicles> dateTimes ) {
    Vehicles cars = new Vehicles();
    cars.getMatricula();
    parkingSlots.add(cars);
    System.out.println("Matricula:" + cars.getMatricula());
    
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    cars.getDatesTimes(dateTime);
    
    System.out.println("Fecha de entrada:"+ dateTime);
    
    parkingSlots.add(cars);
}
```

y esta para los constructores:

```
public class Vehicles {

String matricula;
LocalDateTime DatesTimes;
ArrayList<String> parkinSlots;

public Vehicles(String matricula) {
    this.matricula = matricula;
}

public Vehicles() {
    
}

public Vehicles(LocalDateTime DatesTimes) {
    this.DatesTimes = DatesTimes;
}

public LocalDateTime getDatesTimes(LocalDateTime DatesTimes) {
    return DatesTimes;
}


public String getMatricula(){
    char[] letras = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
    String matricula = " ";
    for (int i=0; i< 7; i++){
        int let = (int)(Math.random() * letras.length); 
        int num = (int)(Math.random() * 10); 
        if (i>3) {
            matricula = matricula + letras[let];
        } else {
            matricula = matricula +  num;
        }
    }

    return matricula;
  }
}
```

No sé si lo estoy haciendo bien o me falta algo.

Answer (score 0):

Este es un ejemplo básico de lo que creo que necesitas hacer:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Garage {
    
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Vector<Vehiculo> aparcados = new Vector(1,1); // Nos permite almacenar objetos con diferentes tipos de datos
        int i = 0;
        while(i<3) {                                  // Este while reemplazarlo para manejar el flujo del programa 
            Vehiculo vehiculo = new Vehiculo();       // Instanciamos e inicializamos objeto de una clase   
            ingresarVehiculo(vehiculo);               // Aplicamos al objeto el método que lo edita 
            System.out.println();
            i += 1;                                   // El índice para iterar
            aparcados.addElement(vehiculo);           // addElement es un método de la clase Vector
        }
            
            for (Vehiculo vehiculo : aparcados) {     // Iteramos el vector para ver los elemntos   
                System.out.println("Patente: " + vehiculo.getPatente() + " " +
                                   "Fecha: " + vehiculo.getFecha() + " " +
                                   "Hora de ingreso: " + vehiculo.getHora());
                System.out.println();
            }

        }
    
        public static void ingresarVehiculo(Vehiculo unidad) {  // Método para editar los atributos del vehiculo a ingresar
            System.out.println("Ingrese la patente: ");
            unidad.setFecha(LocalDate.now());
            unidad.setHora(LocalTime.now());
            unidad.setPatente(scan.next());
        }
    
    }

class Vehiculo{  // Esta clase determina un entidad la cual debe ser los + abstracta posible
                 
    private LocalDate fecha;  // No puede haber atributos que no sea própio de la entidad
    private String patente;
    private LocalTime hora;
    
    // Getters y Setters
    public LocalDate getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }
    public void setFecha(LocalDate fecha) {  
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }
    public String getPatente() {
        return patente;
    }
    public void setPatente(String patente) {
        this.patente = patente;
    }
    public LocalTime getHora() {
        return hora;
    }
    public void setHora(LocalTime hora) {
        this.hora = hora;
    }
    
}
```

Investigando podes usar un método para convertir en mayúsculas las letras ingresadas además de poder seguir abstrayendo aun más para no recargar la lógica en el main. También podrías codificar un método que modifique el objeto específico del Vector cuando un cliente retira el auto agregar la hora y fecha de tal evento, siempre agregando atributos a la entidad, como puede ser también agregar el pago. Luego podes simular una base de datos creando un archivo txt con los datos y que se puede editar, hay mucho para meter mano en este mundo, espero te sirva el aporte y este lo más correcto aceptable, saludos.